# Как сделать динамическое обновление ToolTip'a на иконке в трее в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Как сделать динамическую смену данных в *ToolTip*, на иконке в трее?

Надо, чтобы после каждого изменения переменной, в динамике выводилось значение, без перезагрузки программы.

```
void Tray::showTrayIcon()
{
MainWindow w;

//Стопорим программу для обработки
QEventLoop loop;
QTimer::singleShot(1000, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();

QIcon trayImage(":/images/images/tray.png");
trayIcon -> setIcon(trayImage);
trayIcon -> setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);

balanceUser = w.searchBalance();
trayIcon->setToolTip(tr("Баланс: %1").arg(balanceUser));

// Подключаем обработчик клика по иконке...
//connect(trayIcon, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)), this, SLOT(trayIconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));

// Выводим значок...
trayIcon -> show();

if(balanceUser < 0)
    trayIcon->showMessage("Отрицательный баланс", "На балансе нету средств, "
                                                  "пополните счёт если хотите продолжать пользоваться услугами!");
}
```

Comment: Покажите как сейчас в ToolTip значение пишете.

Comment: Код реализации выложил выше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятных решений может быть несколько, предложу два:

1. Простое.

Храните указатель на созданный объект `QSystemTrayIcon` в объекте вашего класса `MainWindow` (или ещё где-то, где вам удобно).

По таймеру (или по некоторому внешнему сигналу) получаете обновлённое значение баланса и вызываете метод:

```
systray_->setToolTip(QString("Баланс %1 у.е").arg(newBalance));
```

2. Более сложное.

Отнаследоваться от класса `QSystemTrayIcon` и определить слот:

```
public slots:
  void slotUpdateBalance(int newBalance)
  {
    setToolTip(QString("На балансе %1 у.е").arg(newBalance));
    // Здесь можно вызвать showMessage(...), сохранить новое значение баланса или выполнить ещё какие-нибудь важные действия
  }
```

В вашем классе `MainWindow` объявить сигнал

```
signals:
  void balanceUpdated(int newBalance);
```

отслеживать событие изменения баланса (например, по таймеру) и испускать этот сигнал:

```
emit balanceUpdated(newBalance);
```

Предварительно соединяем сигнал со слотом:

```
connect(mainwindow, SIGNAL(balanceUpdated(int)), systemtray, SLOT(slotUpdateBalance(int)));
```

Примерный код:

```
class MainWindow
{
  MainWindow() :
    balance_(getBalance()),
    systemtray_(new YourSystemTray(this))
  {
    // Особенности вашей реализации.
    // ...
    // Затем:

    connect(this, SIGNAL(balanceUpdated(int)), systemtray_, SLOT(slotUpdateBalance(int)));

    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slotCheckBalance()));
    timer->start(1000);
  }

  signals:
    void balanceUpdated(int newBalance);

  private slots:
    void slotCheckBalance()
    {
      int newBalance = getBalance();
      if (balance_ != newBalance) {
        balance_ = newBalance;
        emit balanceUpdated(balance_);
      }
    }

  private:
    int getBalance(); // Предполагается, что здесь вы получаете текущее значение баланса

    int balance_;
    YourSystemTray* systemtray_;
};

  class YourSystemTray : public QSystemTrayIcon
  {
     // Ваша реализация

   public slots:
     void slotUpdateBalance(int newBalance)
     {
       setToolTip(QString("На балансе %1 у.е.").arg(newBalance));
     }
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, единственное что придётся всю реализацию трея переписать!

Comment: Зачем всё то переписывать? Вы ж наверняка `QSystemTray` используете? Да и вообще, я предложил лишь вариант реализации. Можно ведь и по-другому написать.

Comment: Например, хранить указатель на объект `QSystemTray` в вашем `MainWindow` и, не городя всего огорода, прямо в слоте `slotCheckBalance` вызывать `systemtray_->setToolTip(...)`. Так, пожалуй, мне даже больше нравится.

Comment: @LevBazdyrev, обновил ответ, с учётом моего комментария выше.

Comment: В принципе MainWindow это по факту даже не основной файл, это просто окошко для реализции настроек приложения. Вся описывается в int main(), поэтому наверное лучше хранить указатель в main()